# How to trigger a Kubernetes controller reconciler for an arbitrary object?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-operator, kubebuilder

## Overview

I am writing a Kubernetes controller for a VerticalScaler CRD that can vertically scale a Deployment in the cluster. My spec references an existing Deployment object in the cluster. I'd like to enqueue a reconcile request for a VerticalScaler if the referenced Deployment is modified or deleted.

```golang
// VerticalScalerSpec defines the desired state of VerticalScaler.
type VerticalScalerSpec struct {
    // Name of the Deployment object which will be auto-scaled.
    DeploymentName string `json:"deploymentName"`
}
```

### Question

Is there a good way to watch an arbitrary resource when that resource is not owned by the controller, and the resource does not hold a reference to the object whose resource is managed by the controller?

## What I Found

I think this should be configured in the Kubebuilder-standard [SetupWithManager](https://sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/building-operators/golang/tutorial/#resources-watched-by-the-controller) function for the controller, though it's possible a watch could be set up someplace else.

```golang
// SetupWithManager sets up the controller with the Manager.
func (r *VerticalScalerReconciler) SetupWithManager(mgr ctrl.Manager) error {
    return ctrl.NewControllerManagedBy(mgr).
        For(&v1beta1.VerticalScaler{}).
        Complete(r)
}
```

I've been searching for a good approach in [controller-runtime/pkg/builder](https://pkg.go.dev/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.8.3/pkg/builder) and the Kubebuilder docs. The closest example I found was the section "Watching Arbitrary Resources" in the [kubebuilder-v1 docs on watches](https://book-v1.book.kubebuilder.io/beyond_basics/controller_watches.html):

> Controllers may watch arbitrary Resources and map them to a key of the Resource managed by the controller. Controllers may even map an event to multiple keys, triggering Reconciles for each key.
>
> Example: To respond to cluster scaling events (e.g. the deletion or addition of Nodes), a Controller would watch Nodes and map the watch events to keys of objects managed by the controller.

My challenge is how to map the Deployment to the depending VerticalScaler(s), since this information is not present on the Deployment. I could [create an index](https://pkg.go.dev/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/client#hdr-Indexing) on the VerticalScaler and look up depending VerticalScalers from the [MapFunc](https://pkg.go.dev/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.8.3/pkg/handler#MapFunc) using a field selector, but it doesn't seem like I should do I/O inside a MapFunc. If the list-Deployments operation failed I would be unable to retry or re-enqueue the change.

I have this code working using this imperfect approach:

```golang
const deploymentNameIndexField = ".metadata.deploymentName"

// SetupWithManager sets up the controller with the Manager.
func (r *VerticalScalerReconciler) SetupWithManager(mgr ctrl.Manager) error {
    if err := r.createIndices(mgr); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return ctrl.NewControllerManagedBy(mgr).
        For(&v1beta1.VerticalScaler{}).
        Watches(
            &source.Kind{Type: &appsv1.Deployment{}},
            handler.EnqueueRequestsFromMapFunc(r.mapDeploymentToRequests)).
        Complete(r)
}

func (r *VerticalScalerReconciler) createIndices(mgr ctrl.Manager) error {
    return mgr.GetFieldIndexer().IndexField(
        context.Background(),
        &v1beta1.VerticalScaler{},
        deploymentNameIndexField,
        func(object client.Object) []string {
            vs := object.(*v1beta1.VerticalScaler)

            if vs.Spec.DeploymentName == "" {
                return nil
            }

            return []string{vs.Spec.DeploymentName}
        })
}

func (r *VerticalScalerReconciler) mapDeploymentToRequests(object client.Object) []reconcile.Request {
    deployment := object.(*appsv1.Deployment)

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Minute)
    defer cancel()

    var vsList v1beta1.VerticalScalerList

    if err := r.List(ctx, &vsList,
        client.InNamespace(deployment.Namespace),
        client.MatchingFields{deploymentNameIndexField: deployment.Name},
    ); err != nil {
        r.Log.Error(err, "could not list VerticalScalers. " +
            "change to Deployment %s.%s will not be reconciled.",
            deployment.Name, deployment.Namespace)
        return nil
    }

    requests := make([]reconcile.Request, len(vsList.Items))

    for i, vs := range vsList.Items {
        requests[i] = reconcile.Request{
            NamespacedName: client.ObjectKeyFromObject(&vs),
        }
    }

    return requests
}
```

### Other Considered Approaches

Just to cover my bases I should mention I don't want to set the VerticalScaler as an owner of the Deployment because I don't want to garbage collect the Deployment if the VerticalScaler is deleted. Even a non-controller ownerReference causes garbage collection.

I also considered using a [Channel](https://pkg.go.dev/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.8.3/pkg/source#Channel) watcher, but the docs say that is for events originating from outside the cluster, which this is not.

I could also create a separate controller for the Deployment, and update some field on the depending VerticalScaler(s) from that controller's Reconcile function, but then I would also need a finalizer to handle triggering a VerticalScaler reconcile when a Deployment is deleted, and that seems like overkill.

I could have my VerticalScaler reconciler add an annotation to the Deployment, but there's a probability that the Deployment annotations can be overwritten if managed by for example Helm. That also would not cause a reconcile request in the case where the VerticalScaler is created before the Deployment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do indeed use a map function and a normal watch. https://github.com/coderanger/migrations-operator/blob/088a3b832f0acab4bfe02c03a4404628c5ddfd97/components/migrations.go#L64-L91 shows an example. You do end up often having to do I/O in the map function to work out which of the root objects this thing corresponds to, but I agree it kind of sucks that there's no way to do much other than log or panic if those calls fail.

You can also use non-controller owner references or annotations as a way to store the mapped target for a given deployment which makes the map function much simpler, but also usually less responsive. Overall it depends on how dynamic this needs to be. Feel free to pop on the #kubebuilder Slack channel for help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I might try using a map function. However because it does not have any retry or re-enqueue mechanism if the API call to list Deployments fails, there is a potential for missing a Deployment update.

I tried using a non-controller owner reference, but even then it caused garbage collection on the Deployment when I deleted the VerticalScaler.

An annotation sounds like it could work, but because the Deployment is managed by Helm, it may overwrite the annotation, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to `EnqueueRequestsFromMapFunc`, you can use:

```golang
ctrl.NewControllerManagedBy(mgr).
    For(&v1beta1.VerticalScaler{}).
    Watches(
        &source.Kind{Type: &appsv1.Deployment{}},
        handler.Funcs{CreateFunc: r.CreateFunc})...
```

The handler's callback functions such as the `CreateFunc` above that you'd define, has the signature `func(event.CreateEvent, workqueue.RateLimitingInterface)`, giving you direct access to the workqueue. By default if you don't call `Done()` on the workqueue it will get requeued with exponential backoff. This should allow you to handle errors with io operations.

Comment: Could you please expand a bit on this answer ? To my understanding, the custom EventHandler implementation that you describe should call the `Add` merhod of the workqueue to enqueue the event, while the reconcile method will call `Done` (sort of, reconcile result drives re-enqueue or not). In this case, how habing6direct access to workqueue methods allows to requeue the event if the listing I/O fails. Could you provide a short code example of what you have in mind ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question and the clear description of the problem and what you tried. I had exactly same problem and reading your post helped me came up with a possible solution.

In your example this is what I would do:

1. Add following map to *VerticalScalerReconciler*:

`DeploymentMap map[string]string` => *key* is the Deployment namespace/name; *value* is the VerticalScaler namespace/name that references such Deployment;
2. Watch Deployments for changes with a *MapFunc*

Anytime you reconcile a VeriticalScaler, first thing update above map.

When Deployment changes, your registered MapFunc will be invoked. Instead of doing a VerticalScaler list (as you pointed out if that fails, it is a problem) use the DeploymentMap. So you immediately know which VeriticalScaler needs to be reconciled.

It can happen that you have a VerticalScaler A referencing a Deployment. Its reconciliation is still queued and before that happens, Deployment changes.

In this scenarios, your MapFunc will return empty `[]reconcile.Request` (DeploymentMap does not know yet  about VerticalScaler A).  That is not a problem though as your VerticalScaler A is already queued for a reconciliation.

In case multiple VerticalScalers can reference the same Deployment, the map should be `map[string][]string`

Since this is an old post, I am also interested if you found a different/better solution meanwhile. Thank you.